# where does MySQL store database files?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, recover

I have uninstall wamp server and now I need my database to restore. How can I do this process?

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a program for accessing databases, I think your question is "Where are MySQL databases stored?"

Comment: @BrendanLong I understand the question was originally about phpmyadmin. So, where does phpmyadmin read the database from? Is this directory setupable? I want mysql to be on separate container, is it possible? (Please let me know if this would be subject to another SO question; I can not find right answers.)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In any case you can know it:

```
mysql> select @@datadir;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@datadir                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| D:\Documents and Settings\b394382\My Documents\MySQL_5_1\data\ |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks Barry Galbraith from the MySql Forum http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,379153,379167#msg-379167

Comment: much more useful answer for any mysql installation, thanks bud.

Comment: @Andrew agreed, this helped me as well since it was much more general.

Comment: Being on a shared host with no visibility into the file system, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 27):

WAMP stores the db data under `WAMP\bin\mysql\mysql(version)\data`. Where the WAMP folder itself is depends on where you installed it to (on xp, I believe it is directly in the main drive, for example `c:\WAMP\...`

If you deleted that folder, or if the uninstall deleted that folder, if you did not do a DB backup before the uninstall, you may be out of luck.

If you did do a backup though phpmyadmin, then login, and click the import tab, and browse to the backup file.

Comment: Thanks!  I found this answer while running a search on my hard drive looking for the same thing.  I have a xampp installation with MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows 7.  For others with a similar setup:  I found my data file at C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data.  On my system I had to manually type in "C:\ProgramData".

Comment: @Cryophallion hey this is is of no use I think. Since, when I copied the database from the location which you have intimidated and pasted it on another computer which has same mysql location. The positive side is that it shows the database and the tables in query browser but when I open the table it shows “got error 1 from storage engine error no 1030″

Answer (score 18):

Check your `my.cnf` file in your MySQL program directory, look for

```
[mysqld]
datadir=
```

The `datadir` is the location where your MySQL database is stored.

Comment: on linux, this file is usually at:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

and the database files are at

/var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 4):

**another way from *MySQL Workbench*:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For WampServer, click on its tray icon and then in the popup cascading menu select

```
MySQL | MySQL settings | datadir
```

[image: MySQL Data Directory]