# Recover local databases after WAMP uninstall

Tags: wamp

I uninstalled and reinstalled Wamp. When I did this, I lost all my databases on localhost. I did not think about it, and did not imagine that it would delete them all.

Is there a way to recover those local databases?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup of the DB would be nice!

If not, you may have to go to data recovery tool (list of [recovery file software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software), from wikipedia).

MySQL store the DB in the file system; when you drop a DB, you are deleting the files of that DB in your server's file system.

Search for the MySQL config file for the directory that has the files to know exaclty where your files had been.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091367/2550094); explains where to find that config file and your MySQL directoy.

Once you have the directory, you could try the recovery program to restore the deleted files.

If you succeed, you may want to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12947713/2550094), that explain the steps to recover DB from files in MySQL and the file structure of MySQL.

Hope your files still there! and do a daily backup.