# Create DB in PHP and save it in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database using a PHP page loaded on localhost on my PC using the following code:

```
// Connect to MySQL
$linkdb = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '***********');
if (!$linkdb) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
// Make my_db the current database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('movie_db', $linkdb);
if (!$db_selected) {
    // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
    $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE movie_db';
    if (mysql_query($sql, $linkdb)) {
        echo "Database movie_db created successfully\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error creating database: '.mysql_error()."\n";
    }
}
mysql_close($linkdb);
```

As I loaded the page on the browser the first time at

> localhost/~"my name"/

I got this

> Database movie_db created successfully

meaning that the database was created.
The problem is that I can't find the database anywhere. When should it be stored?
Is there anyway to save it in the same folder of the .php file?

Comment: Normally MySQL stores its files at a predefined location that depends on your operating system (Windows, Linux, ...). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091350/5830574) gives useful hints on this. In short: it _is_ possible to store the files in the same folder as your .php files but definitely not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see why is not recommended, but I'm gonna put this script on a server online and I will need to download that database file. It would be easier if it was placed in the same folder as the php.

Comment: I see. But if you want to _backup_ your DB then [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) is your friend. Google for it to see numerous examples how to use it. It's really simple.

Comment: Use a tool like MySQL Workbench, HeidiSQL or phpMyAdmin to export and import a MySQL-database

Comment: Thanks @PerlDog I'm gonna take a look at that after dinner.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, as I explained to the guy who answered below, I'm not gonna interact with the server at all. I'm just gonna put the file up there, call the php page from my computer, the page will generate a db with certain data in a certain position, I will download the db from that position.

Comment: Why don't you just run your creation script on the remote (online) server?

Comment: That is what I will do when the entire script will be complete. Now I'm just testing it in local, and I was trying to understand  some things.

Comment: Just to get it right: The _only_ way you can interact with your website is by uploading a .php script (plus .css etc.) and then call that script via your browser? But – enjoy your meal! (as I will now)

Comment: It is not a website. Long story short: I made an Android app which collects data from several websites parsing their html codes. I decided to reduce the connection to 1. I made a php script, set in php file w/o html or css, which collects all the parts I need and `echo`them. Still I will have to parse on my app. I was thinking to reduce the load storing all the important parts in a small db which my app will. Does that sound crazy/ridiculous/unreachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your question refers to MySQL, I'd like to suggest SQLite which seems to fit your use-case better. It stores the database in a single file and can be accessed directly through `sqlite_xxx()` functions or via PDO.

Here's some example code of what that would look like:

```
$folder = 'sqlite:/<PATH>/movie_db.sqlite';
$dbh  = new PDO($folder);
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name LIKE '%love%'";

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    echo $row[0];
```

You can also find out more about SQLite at:
https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Comment: This may be a good solution. Do you have any knowledge about if Android has support for SQLite?

Comment: I was able to find this: [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks a thousand. I'm gonna go with this.

Answer (score 0):

The database is created on the MySQL server.

> With PHP, you can connect to and manipulate databases.
>
> MySQL is the most popular database system used with PHP.
>
> What is MySQL? MySQL is a database system used on the web MySQL is a
>   database system that runs on a server MySQL is ideal for both small
>   and large applications MySQL is very fast, reliable, and easy to use
>   MySQL uses standard SQL MySQL compiles on a number of platforms MySQL
>   is free to download and use MySQL is developed, distributed, and
>   supported by Oracle Corporation MySQL is named after co-founder Monty
>   Widenius's daughter: My The data in a MySQL database are stored in
>   tables. A table is a collection of related data, and it consists of
>   columns and rows.
>
> Databases are useful for storing information categorically.

Here you can learn more about the PHP and MySQL basics: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. Is there any way to materially know the location of the file, or better save it in a certain folder?

Comment: You can use phpMyAdmin to access, browse and backup the database.

Comment: I'm not gonna interact with the server at all. I'm just put the file up there, call the php page from my computer, the page will generate a db with certain data in a certain position, I will download the db from that position.

Comment: basically you can not download the database from the server, it's not a single file, it's more like a part of the mysql server. but, phpMyAdmin allows you to login into the mysql server and dump a database as a single file to your local folder.